Post form data inside an array of objects
Hello I've been working in a blog to post blogs, you can add images too
For add image system i use Multer and Path.
To save the image, I save it in a FormData, with its key, so Multer can read the FormData key when making the POST request
But here is the problem. When i post a blog, i add the name, the post body, and the image saved in a formdata, everything saved in an array that is later sent to the backend with axios
So the formdata is saved into a array of objects
My question is how Multer, can read the formdata stored in the array
Here is the code i use for image and post\
Function to post the blog:
const [file, setFile] = useState(); //file is the image submited by the input file
  const formdata = new FormData(); //the formdata

  const params = useParams()
  
  const handleFile = (e) => {
    setFile(e.target.files[0])
  }
  
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await createBlogRequest(targeted) //here I invoke the axios function

      console.log(response)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
    setNewUser('')
    setNewPost('')
  }
  formdata.append('image', file)
  const targeted = {name: newUser, post: newPost, image: formdata} //here is the array with the parts of the blog

The axios function:
export const createBlogRequest = async (blog) =>{
    await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/blogs', blog)
}

The multer and routes functions
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, './server/images')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + "_" + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
})
const upload = multer({
    storage: storage
})

router.post('/blogs',upload.single('image'),  createBlog)
//my question is here, how multer when upload.single('image') can read the formdata inside the array

I hope you understand because I don't speak English.
Any response will be welcome

it's usually done the other way around: add JSON to formdata instead: formdata.append('post', JSON.stringify(newPost)) etc. and on the server read it from body: req.body.post
